# Temporally truncate BOLD data

Tags: neuroimaging, fmri, analysis

I'm analyzing some resting-state data and some of the scans are 10 min while others are 7 min. I need to cut the last 3 min off of those with 10 min scans so everyone has 7 min of resting-state data. I realize I could just delete timeseries columns after processing but I'd like to perform the truncation earlier so that my temporal filtering isn't biased. I believe there's an FSL tool to accomplish this but can't find it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome. Great question. I just wish to note that we unfortunately don't have dedicated imaging folks hanging around here afaik. I inquired over at [Bioinformatics](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/) a while ago, but they basically have the same hiatus. Good luck.

Comment: @AliceD thank you for your response. Alas, it seems like there is just no place in this world for a lost neuroimaging researcher...

Comment: @GWarner I think most people rely on the software-specific communities. https://www.jiscmail.ac.uk/cgi-bin/webadmin?A0=fsl for you. Ultimately this is just a software limitation, since I do most of my data analysis in Matlab I would have completely different advice to give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `fslroi` is the tool I'm looking for. To temporally truncate a scan the usage would be `fslroi <input> <output> <tmin> <tsize>` where `<tmin>` would be zero and `<tsize>` would be the number of volumes you want to keep. Now I just need to figure out how many volumes make up 7 minutes...

Comment: Great that you answered your own question. You can accept it too.